# Ngnix Reverse Proxy Setup SSL For Localhost In Docker

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy, docker-compose

Using below docker compose.yml I am creating 2 containers and a reverse proxy container..

```
version: '3'

services:
  # SSGTM Tag Server Container
  tagging_server_container:
    image: gcr.io/cloud-tagging-10302018/gtm-cloud-image:stable
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    restart: always
    environment:
      PREVIEW_SERVER_URL: https://preview.ssgtm.dev
      CONTAINER_CONFIG: aWQ9...
    networks:
      - ssgtm
  # SSGTM Preview Server Container
  preview_server_container:
    image: gcr.io/cloud-tagging-10302018/gtm-cloud-image:stable
    ports:
      - '8081:8080'
    restart: always
    environment:
      RUN_AS_PREVIEW_SERVER: true
      CONTAINER_CONFIG: aWQ9...
    networks:
      - ssgtm
  proxy:
    image: nginx:1.19.10-alpine
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./certs:/etc/nginx/certs
    depends_on:
      - preview_server_container
      - tagging_server_container
    networks:
      - ssgtm
networks:
  ssgtm:
    driver: bridge
```

And also inside `conf/nginx.conf` and used `mkcert -cert-file ssgtm.dev.crt -key-file ssgtm.dev.key ssgtm.dev "*.ssgtm.dev" localhost 127.0.0.1 ::1` for creating SSL cert & key.

```
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  
  upstream docker-tagging-server {
    server tagging_server_container:8080;
  }

  upstream docker-preview-server {
    server preview_server_container:8080;
  }
  
  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/cert.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    location / {
      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_redirect  off;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;

      proxy_pass http://docker-preview-server;
    }
  }
  
  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name ssgtm.dev;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/cert.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    location / {
      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_redirect  off;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;

      proxy_pass http://docker-tagging-server;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name preview.ssgtm.dev;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/cert.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    location / {
      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_redirect  off;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;

      proxy_pass http://docker-preview-server;
    }
  }
}
```

Where I am proxying my VirtualHost requests to target container.

Also in `hosts` file I have added below to resolve locally. Which works just fine... It is resolving to 127.0.0.1 and going to Nginx and going to their target container.

```
127.0.0.1 preview.ssgtm.dev
::1 preview.ssgtm.dev

127.0.0.1 ssgtm.dev
::1 ssgtm.dev
```

The problem I am facing is... inside both of the container app does request a TCP to Domain IP with 443 port... so when it does request to ssgtm.dev:443 it becomes 127.0.0.1:443 and it returns error `Message: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443` And I am unable to understand this error. As far as I understand It's unable to connect to 127.0.0.1 with port 443 but I have added that! What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The containers are unable to reach Nginx because they are trying to connect to the localhost of their own network namespace, we could try the special DNS `name host.docker.internal` which resolves to the internal IP address used by the host.

Modify your `nginx.conf` file so that instead of making requests to `ssgtm.dev:443` or `127.0.0.1:443`, it should make requests to `host.docker.internal:443`.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name host.docker.internal;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/cert.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    location / {
      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_redirect  off;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;

      proxy_pass http://docker-preview-server;
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's not working, how do i enable VirtualHost as along with SSL and Container connection to each other?